# How to translate linq query to a human readable string

Tags: .net, linq, debugging, expression

How do I translate a linq query (or a expression like below) to a human readable string? Useful for debugging purposes.

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> query
```

**Edit**

Since it was hard to understand: I want to get a string from the expression. Hence the example declaration of the expression.

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> query2 = 
   u => u.FirstName.StartsWith("J") && u.LastName == "Gauffin";
```

Should print something like "FirstName startswith 'J' and LastName equals 'Gauffin'";

Comment: This is only a declaration, as such, there is no query, so what do you want to "translate" into a human readable string?

Comment: Have some imagination. For you that don't have it: Updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tip:
if you are querying using linq to sql or entity framework you can use the ToString() method on the IQueryable object to get the query in sql:

query2.ToString() gives something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FirstName LIKE 'J%' AND LastName="Gauffin"
```

Comment: there's also another way to capture the sql queries which is to use the Log property of the data context class, something like, datacontext.Log = Console.Out

Answer (score 1):

Check out the LINQ Expression Visualizer in the VS samples folder.

Alternatively in LINQ to SQL you can see it using the DataContext.Log

In Entity Framework you cast the LINQ query to an ObjectQuery and call ToTraceString